# Odd characters in memory

Tags: memory, debugging

While I was running my debugger I decided to examine a specific spot in memory and noticed that there are some odd characters ¾㵎䐑톢హ��洓. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Did you try to translate them from Chinese :) ?

Comment: It means you have a virus from china, better run a virus scan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's random bytes in memory being (mis-)interpreted as Unicode characters.